# <br> does not work in my while

Tags: php

I come to you because I encounter a problem with my `while loop`.

I did a `while loop` to get the id of tickets and ticket titles.

Except that, I want to add a `<br>` but it does not work, it does not move.

I tried with two `<br> <br>` it's the same, can you help me please?

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<?php while ($row = $req_5->fetch()) { ?>
   <a href="ticket.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_ticket']; ?>"><?php echo $row['titre']."<br><br>"; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: br tag has to be outside a tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php while ($row = $req_5->fetch()) { ?>
    <a href="ticket.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_ticket']; ?>"><?php echo $row['titre']?></a>
    <br><br>
<?php } ?
```

just put the break tag outside of the anchor element